# Separating one element of an Svg file into multiple elements with Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, svg

I want to edit an [svg](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/54/Circulatory_System_en_edited.svg) from wikimedia commons that shows the human arteries to highlite a specific artery in a specific color. Unfortunately multiple arteries in that svg are represented by the same svg object. What's the best way for editing files like that to be able to select different subparts and color them?

Comment: Have you tried to copy, paste, align to the original arteries and edit the nodes of the copy?

Comment: Quick Guess: *Break Apart* and *Ungroup.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Inkscape we can break apart the path at a desired location.

1. Ungroup all paths from the source SVG
2. Select nodes from where we wish to break the path

   [image]
3. Tick *Break Path at selected nodes* [image]
4. Choose *Path > Break apart* <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>
5. Select the now generated new object to then change it's color (or delete it, move it, etc.)

   [image]

In case there are no pre-existing nodes at the location we need to break we can always manually add new ones.

Comment: Can this be done via Inkscape CLI?

Comment: @MateuszGebroski: you may need visual control for the objects to select. This can not be done from CLI.

Comment: And what about any coding? Maybe any library for this? It can be in any language. I just need to select whole svg image and then do break apart on this.. nothing more

Answer (score 2):

In Illustrator I would Knife Tool the large artery path to isolate the part I want:

[image]

However in Inkscape I don't believe a Knife Tool exists. Here are instructions on doing a Knife Tool like process in Inkscape (which is the Node method Paolo mentioned in comment): http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=961

But at that point it might be easier to just open Inkscape and draw a new path on top instead of cutting the existing path.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldnt use Inkscape I would use a code editor in this instance.  You can open the SVG file and you could pullout and test the paths, in this case:

```
<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="path351" fill="#ED5D40" d="M357.395,214.812c-2.646-3.05-6.138-7.847-10.553-8.137c-1.53-0.1-3.363,0.666-4.316,1.871    c2.714,1.652-4.842,5.748-6.275,4.082c1.855,2.163-2.439,3.265-3.823,3.567c-1.448,0.317-2.215,0.128-3.587-0.18    c-1.734-0.391-3.451,0.485-4.984,1.179c-6.429,2.912-7.636,10.117-5.79,16.435c1.497,5.132,3.86,10.467,7.753,14.243    c2.068,2.009,4.276,2.552,6.684,3.871c2.48,1.358,4.274,2.92,7.157,3.681c4.021,1.06,7.828-0.449,11.841-0.435    c1.721,0.005,3.318,0.613,5.08,0.688c2.136,0.093,4.279-0.057,6.406,0.173c5.291,0.575,10.852-5.71,10.705-10.759    c-0.067-2.307-1.234-4.621-1.976-6.778c-1.483-4.324-3.636-8.563-6.132-12.375C363.125,222.186,360.369,218.237,357.395,214.812z"/>
```

Is the heart:

[image]

What I did was use Chrome's Inspect Element to tell me it was the heart:

[image]

If you notice in the DOCTYPE it tells you how it was created:

```
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd" [
    <!ENTITY ns_extend "http://ns.adobe.com/Extensibility/1.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_ai "http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeIllustrator/10.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_graphs "http://ns.adobe.com/Graphs/1.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_vars "http://ns.adobe.com/Variables/1.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_imrep "http://ns.adobe.com/ImageReplacement/1.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_sfw "http://ns.adobe.com/SaveForWeb/1.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_custom "http://ns.adobe.com/GenericCustomNamespace/1.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_adobe_xpath "http://ns.adobe.com/XPath/1.0/">
]>
```

Which most of this could be modified to just include that its an SVG.

To answer your question: "What's the best way for editing files like that to be able to select different subparts and color them?"

I would open everything in a code editor and manipulate the fill and you can even add [styling with CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html) to them.

Since you are wanting to target the arteries you could either open each one up and modify each one.  Since you are using Inkscape you would have to duplicate each one and adjust the anchors to their desired area.  Either way this will be a timely process.  If you want to target a hole section you would have to see how it was built.  Such as this is one artery path but not all the arteries:

```
<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="path31" fill="#A9B5BF" stroke="#aeaeaeae" stroke-width="0.3195" d="M225.042,280.882c0.488-1.744-1.58-3.372-2.583-4.605    c-0.912-1.12-2.26-2.398-2.585-3.865c-0.631-2.846,0.775-6.412,1.146-9.236c0.564-4.289,1.083-8.584,1.638-12.875    c0.254-1.973,0.345-4.08,0.744-6.017c0.342-1.655,0.775-1.766,1.673-0.27c0.589,0.981,0.955,1.966,1.418,3.02    c0.842,1.919,2.059,4.297,2.653,5.878c0.827-1.267-0.796-3.559-1.401-4.779c-1.537-3.093-3.287-6.523-3.192-10.071    c0.102-3.82,1.453-7.84,2.118-11.605c0.497-2.815,1.616-5.385,1.892-8.235c0.261-2.681,1.254-5.493,2.131-8.072    c1.137-3.343,2.387-6.65,3.804-9.887c0.658-1.5,1.647-2.836,2.215-4.377c0.567-1.536,0.692-3.75,2.174-4.755    c0.271,3.523,0.475,7.207,1.303,10.622c1.591-0.928,0.067-4.717-0.039-6.385c-0.37-5.819,2.823-9.721,6.95-13.376    c4.646-4.116,10.072-7.327,15.839-9.602c4.137-1.633,8.292-3.075,12.707-3.794c5.268-0.856,10.467-1.625,15.781-0.628    c3.542,0.664,6.108,1.436,8.944,3.622c2.85,2.198,5.152,4.993,7.606,7.598c2.562,2.718,5.021,5.514,7.232,8.52    c1.429,1.938,4.453,4.745,4.454,7.333c0.001,1.457-0.981,3.16-1.122,4.702c-0.158,1.728-0.07,3.49,0.245,5.196    c0.741,4.043,2.473,7.824,4.069,11.583c0.974,2.295,1.41,2.516,3.881,2.701c1.99,0.149,3.795,0.065,5.696-0.706    c0.671-0.272,5.946-3.607,5.041-4.598c-2.123-2.324-6.477-13.548-2.684-15.657c-0.119,0.067,1.139,2.735,1.257,2.973    c3.57-0.861,9.044-7.422,7.453-11.265c-1.219-2.946-4.068-3.971-6.849-4.567c0.459,0.098,1.681-4.026,1.972-4.599    c3.796-7.441,13.682-13.374,21.882-14.378c11.962-1.465,22.988,4.76,31.041,13.144c5.853,6.093,9.604,13.535,11.986,21.582    c1.105,3.736,2.515,7.892,2.468,11.824c-0.053,4.681-2.095,9.088-3.531,13.458c-1.552,4.715-2.15,9.498-1.88,14.443    c0.558,10.083,4.409,19.357,6.346,29.201c-0.708-3.603-0.973-7.132-1.983-10.769c-0.885-3.174-1.512-6.58-2.099-9.841    c-1.358-7.549-0.694-15.435,1.214-22.829c0.469-1.815,1.876-9.359,4.348-5.359c1.87,3.025,1.588,8.362,2.333,11.759    c1.29,5.884,2.578,11.767,3.838,17.657c2.056,9.638,3.52,19.847,5.647,29.646c1.027,4.736,2.736,9.41,3.076,14.226    c0.299,4.175,0.076,6.588-0.944,10.783c-0.673,2.766-1.096,5.612-1.51,8.421c-0.691,4.701-1.066,9.435-1.063,14.203    c0.009,16.608,3.299,33.654,6.027,49.976c0.839,5.037,1.712,10.077,2.77,15.067c1.456,6.866,2.974,13.889,3.607,20.865    c0.697,7.691-3.778,9.9-7.69,15.63c-2.958,4.332-4.897,9.617-7.458,14.271c-1.422,2.582-3.125,4.994-4.896,7.348    c-1.697,2.256-4.169,4.672-5.304,7.225c1.692-1.236,3.15-3.18,4.475-4.801c2.977-3.645,5.673-7.813,7.849-11.963    c2.181-4.166,4.118-8.584,6.893-12.406c0.91-1.256,1.987-2.377,3.063-3.486c0.869-0.896,1.563-2.047,2.399-2.889    c0.612,4.922-1.887,8.971-4.105,13.063c-0.987,1.826-2.368,3.324-3.326,5.139c-1.11,2.109-2.138,4.291-2.662,6.631    c-0.291,1.307-0.566,2.447,0.107,3.605c0.758,1.303,1.617,2.596,2.426,3.879c3.337,5.301,10.819,8.314,16.774,9.051    c3.522,0.436,5.979,0.035,9.316-1.271c2.82-1.107,5.938-2.973,7.881-5.383c1.133-1.406,2.077-3.016,2.536-4.766    c0.918-3.506-2.121-6.336-2.209-9.701c-0.092-3.566-1.461-6.836-2.004-10.357c-2.531-16.41-2.964-33.072-4.773-49.62    c-0.645-5.884-0.957-11.653-1.243-17.565c-0.334-6.964,0.666-13.91,0.428-20.855c-0.169-4.958-1.424-10.141-1.901-15.16    c-1.098-11.525-4.988-22.156-13.356-30.371c-2.803-2.752-5.386-5.73-7.388-9.118c-2.523-4.273-4.034-9.985-4.763-14.853    c-1.459-9.763-3.062-19.289-5.078-28.991c-1.963-9.459-3.013-19.292-5.147-28.599c-1.179-5.143-2.662-10.207-4.248-15.249    c-3.762-11.953-6.896-21.696-17.229-29.732c-7.128-5.544-16.09-8.891-25.025-9.966c-3.552-0.427-7.263,0.198-10.66,1.251    c-3.597,1.117-6.496,4.293-9.756,2.038c-3.062-2.117-4.324-6.444-5.931-9.594c-0.862-1.693-1.881-3.251-2.681-4.982    c-0.632-1.367-1.408-2.638-2.073-3.989c-0.408-0.835-0.897-2.533-1.803-2.972c0.225,0.706,0.028,1.47-0.018,2.189    c-0.025,0.428-0.164,0.901-0.107,1.334c0.075,0.555,0.523,1.139,0.751,1.652c0.304,0.687,0.706,1.316,1.088,1.964    c0.844,1.431,1.659,2.879,2.381,4.375c1.27,2.626,2.555,5.252,3.569,7.99c0.746,2.012,2.324,4.622,0.591,6.544    c-1.916,2.124-4.291,3.665-6.051,6.01c-1.767,2.353-2.633,4.836-3.345,7.594c0.348-3.424,0.681-6.845,0.681-10.357    c0-8.597,0.146-17.311,0.399-25.858c0.137-4.621-0.143-9.24-0.427-13.85c-0.253-4.073-1.102-8.739-0.479-12.79    c0.583-3.793,1.59-7.478,2.338-11.246c0.465-2.344,0.964-4.602,1.73-6.859c0.472-1.39,0.667-2.926,1.481-4.18    c1.039-1.592,3.547-2.489,3.586-4.495c-0.921,0.505-2.172,1.07-2.889,1.798c1.233-3.006,1.846-6.229,3.079-9.264    c0.431-1.061,0.978-2.052,1.436-3.089c0.425-0.962,1.19-2.42,1.33-3.438c0.095-0.698-0.215-1.234-0.537-1.94    c-0.411,0.903-0.767,2.458-1.437,3.13c-0.165-0.964-0.255-2.102-0.688-3.014c-0.436,1.184-0.977,1.21-0.641,2.628    c0.18,0.757,0.93,1.927-0.003,2.382c-0.483-0.861-1.021-1.71-1.729-2.375c-0.262,0.957-0.225,1.236,0.203,2.119    c0.316,0.651,0.847,1.532,0.835,2.264c-0.021,1.722-1.524,3.406-1.594,5.145c-0.668-0.574-1.281-1.552-1.733-2.312    c-0.894,2.021,0.78,2.69,0.691,4.489c-0.042,0.81-0.708,2.438-1.201,3.068c-0.68,0.869-0.573,0.451-1.463-0.132    c-1.062,1.21,0.472,2.391,0.375,3.724c-0.09,1.234-1.061,2.746-1.567,3.887c-1.096,2.464-0.924,5.062-0.972,7.764    c0.322-0.755,0.092-1.774,0.138-2.596c0.185-3.361-0.176-6.628,0.03-9.986c0.222-3.573,0.18-7.172,0.4-10.754    c0.141-2.28,0.248-4.57,0.396-6.85c0.289-4.511,0.936-8.949,1.773-13.406c0.475-2.521,0.91-7.635-2.96-7.896    c0.636-0.164,1.313,0.457,1.957,0.458c2.096,0.003,4.782-1.849,6.537-2.84c2.895-1.635,5.146-3.63,7.583-5.881    c0.282-0.26,0.819-0.62,0.963-0.997c0.292-0.774-0.374-1.703-0.333-2.558c-1.716,1.887-3.104,4.028-5.297,5.59    c-1.154,0.821-2.368,1.477-3.593,2.227c-2.563,1.572-5.156,2.797-8.159,3.312c-1.368,0.235-2.139,0.081-3.277,0.918    c-0.854,0.627-1.654,1.302-2.781,1.265c-1.645-0.055-2.879-0.923-3.851-2.146c-0.979-1.231-2.652-2.397-2.854-4.072    c-0.975,0.801-1.26,1.004-0.62,2.22c0.435,0.823,3.604,5.082,4.86,4.39c-2.136,1.176-4.662,1.357-7.149,1.205    c-1.863-0.114-5.178-0.804-6.406-2.4c0.187,0.241,1.975-1.171,2.166-1.412c0.543-0.679,0.944-1.537,1.317-2.319    c0.576-1.206,0.071-1.552-0.642-2.616c-0.651,2.615-3.105,5.482-5.703,6.22c-1.95,0.555-3.354-1.15-5.107-0.834    c-0.367,0.066-0.592,0.328-0.931,0.405c-0.7,0.157-1.608-0.058-2.267-0.237c-2.014-0.548-4.094-1.588-5.646-3    c-1.5-1.365-3.488-2.477-4.444-4.352c-0.399-0.783-0.494-1.917-0.96-2.642c-0.521-0.808-0.508-0.443-1.448-0.779    c-0.238-0.085,0.906,3.807,1.156,4.189c1.255,1.916,3.45,3.904,5.261,5.299c1.63,1.258,5.23,3.988,7.508,3.121    c0.289-0.11,0.803-0.804,1.086-0.987c-2.926,1.415-2.15,6.076-2.078,8.66c0.09,3.15,0.432,6.374,0.916,9.479    c0.496,3.179,0.073,6.411,0.273,9.608c0.184,2.917,0.512,5.854,0.504,8.783c-0.012,3.737,0.1,7.438,0.138,11.169    c-0.429-1.271-0.06-2.874-0.138-4.22c-0.112-1.932-0.975-3.705-1.449-5.531c-0.563-2.172-1.371-4.286-1.98-6.451    c-0.288-1.015-0.201-2.091,0.031-3.11c0.188-0.812,0.725-1.635,0.746-2.472c0.016-0.551-0.318-1.166-0.541-1.649    c-0.166,1.109-0.521,1.966-1.098,2.961c-1.02-1.03-0.562-3.347-0.526-4.622c0.057-2.094,0.037-4.136,0.294-6.251    c0.159-1.323,0.056-1.328-0.772-2.15c-0.124,1.168-0.381,2.542-0.687,3.667c-0.875-0.583-1.516-1.716-2.413-2.438    c-0.006,0.426-0.083,0.727-0.1,1.132c2.844,1.72,2.441,5.479,2.512,8.365c-1-1.03-1.679-2.269-2.778-3.141    c-0.046,0.482,0.024,0.972-0.138,1.428c1.135,1.446,2.461,2.666,2.913,4.56c0.499,2.089,0.785,4.29,1.309,6.37    c-0.807-0.855-1.874-1.565-2.65-2.469c0.025,0.603,0.014,1.518,0.3,2.056c0.262,0.497,1.055,0.809,1.437,1.218    c0.864,0.926,1.222,2.027,1.436,3.231c0.488,2.76,1.53,5.333,2.159,8.044c0.515,2.226,0.616,4.649,1.067,6.937    c0.435,2.184,0.851,4.2,0.99,6.421c0.127,1.995,0.111,3.994,0.232,5.996c0.107,1.732,0.352,3.485,0.533,5.219    c0.382,3.624,0.565,7.222,1.359,10.771c0.862,3.866,1.917,7.689,2.68,11.577c0.547,2.787,0.997,5.607,1.123,8.447    c0.012,0.255-0.22,5.76-0.576,5.583c-1.561-0.777-2.813-1.917-4.525-2.595c-1.408-0.557-2.869-0.966-4.292-1.484    c-2.101-0.764-1.595-0.95-0.972-2.786c0.85-2.501,1.718-4.479,3.18-6.761c1.325-2.072,2.68-4.145,4.061-6.146    c0.453-0.656,0.307-0.931,0.107-1.702c-0.158-0.625-0.158-1.305-0.354-1.908c-0.332,1.169-1.635,2.301-2.33,3.256    c-1.538,2.114-3.278,4.087-4.792,6.219c-1.023,1.444-2.177,2.912-3.326,4.253c-0.712,0.832-1.453,1.436-2.211,2.154    c-2.263,2.137-2.653-0.943-3.37-2.684c-0.476-1.153-1.095-2.013-2.147-2.642c0.025,0.929,1.059,1.498,1.474,2.373    c0.431,0.91,0.454,1.893,0.719,2.811c-0.081-0.279-2.507-1.447-2.853-1.709c-1.499-1.142-2.737-2.685-3.455-4.432    c-0.321-0.78-0.463-1.792-1.24-2.211c0.445,1.981,1.14,4.384,2.715,5.742c-1.199-0.119-2.379-0.353-3.59-0.34    c0.352,1.174,3.419,1.006,4.485,1.437c1.368,0.551,3.018,1.845,3.977,2.939c-1.37,0.07-2.619,0.47-4.003,0.476    c-1.025,0.004-2.065-0.18-3.088-0.122c-5.106,0.281-10.449,1.738-15.351,3.14c-3.265,0.935-6.446,2.161-9.498,3.65    c-4.569,2.23-8.532,5.813-13.147,7.854c-1.238,0.549-8.216,1.838-7.728,3.905c1.446-0.354,2.81-1.092,4.199-1.544    c-0.074,0.921-0.664,1.174-1.231,1.845c-2.671,3.158-3.945,6.38-5.958,9.869c-2.583,4.477-4.567,9.274-6.25,14.152    c-1.885,5.464-2.752,11.276-5.215,16.539c-2.467,5.271-6.356,9.462-9.276,14.458c-0.972,1.665-2.168,3.092-3.402,4.571    c-0.72,0.861-2.497,2.14-2.281,3.359c0.615-0.549,1.43-1.094,2.111-1.518c-1.146,4.079-3.309,8.292-4.801,12.402    c-2.258,6.221-3.518,12.402-2.224,19.007c0.881,4.497,1.343,8.347,0.494,12.944c-0.55,2.979-2.729,7.18-0.744,10.055    c-1.133-2.287,0.337-5.264,1.056-7.432c0.733-2.213,1.063-5.166,0.918-7.53c0.681,0.784,1.195,1.706,1.89,2.471    c0.23-1.552-1.265-3.623-1.626-5.182c-0.512-2.204-0.787-4.459-0.974-6.71c-0.35-4.196-0.088-8.745,0.974-12.83    c1.068-4.114,3.044-7.912,4.592-11.852c0.6-1.529,0.81-3.153,1.229-4.655c0.78-2.797,2.555-5.124,4.341-7.354    c1.094-1.365,4.808-6.048,6.42-2.995c0.949,1.798-0.112,4.898-0.463,6.761c-1.194,6.354-2.387,12.701-3.545,19.07    c-1.51,8.312-3.08,16.576-4.659,24.854c-0.814,4.269-1.693,8.029-3.216,12.069c-1.437,3.812-2.447,8.056-5.265,11.145    c-6.474,7.098-15.045,12.379-20.627,20.33c-1.718,2.446-2.621,5.209-3.461,8.015c-1.182,3.945-2.36,8.159-2.601,12.256    c-0.374,6.333-0.18,12.424-0.959,18.747c-0.911,7.396-1.479,14.876-3.243,22.136c-0.863,3.553-2.344,6.782-2.885,10.372    c-0.564,3.749-1.192,7.479-2.126,11.157c-1.01,3.983-4.058,4.844-7.499,5.784c-3.083,0.843-5.839,2.338-8.336,4.438    c-4.84,4.07-11.853,4.228-16.634,8.289c4.4-2.547,9.657-3.33,14.052-5.963c3.433-2.058,6.814-5.569,11.082-5.596    c3.059-0.02,0.815,1.941-0.136,3.495c-1.418,2.314-2.966,4.55-4.706,6.636c-2.046,2.457-5.417,3.689-8.275,4.912    c-4.053,1.73-8.65,2.236-12.777,3.816c-3.78,1.447-6.114,4.186-9.19,6.744c-2.209,1.838-5.195,4.496-8.289,3.08    c1.935,1.99,5.168,0.113,6.998-1.084c3.117-2.041,5.601-4.746,8.751-6.707c3.569-2.225,7.168-2.973,11.173-3.992    c1.664-0.422,3.392-0.813,4.979-1.375c2.146-0.758,4.689-3.137,2.95,0.457c-1.349,2.787-2.087,5.76-3.309,8.598    c-0.558,1.293-1.291,2.504-1.785,3.824c-0.883,2.361-1.402,4.832-1.846,7.307c-0.426,2.379-0.961,4.777-1.562,7.113    c-1.192,4.646-1.352,9.408-1.886,14.148c-0.234,2.08-0.333,4.162-0.553,6.236c-0.16,1.512-0.489,3.025-0.715,4.525    c-0.146,0.977-0.427,2.145-0.352,3.129c0.014-3.65,0.98-7.414,1.595-11.027c0.358-2.104,0.552-4.252,0.91-6.35    c0.328-1.916,0.355-3.875,0.714-5.787c0.266-1.416,0.686-2.793,0.97-4.205c0.234-1.158,0.761-2.162,1.01-3.313    c0.668-3.084,1.218-6.184,2.103-9.215c0.418-1.434,0.837-2.885,1.519-4.217c0.311-0.607,0.716-1.152,0.999-1.771    c0.225-0.492,0.293-1.031,0.888-1.227c0.396-0.129,1.382,2.754,1.486,3.029c0.32,0.85,0.882,1.869,1.05,2.742    c0.195,1.004-0.556,1.908-0.883,2.793c-0.862,2.332-1.339,4.801-2.234,7.098c-0.844,2.166-2.218,4.021-2.649,6.311    c-0.741,3.938-1.748,7.781-2.601,11.691c-0.332,1.521-0.532,3.047-0.907,4.547c-0.276,1.104-0.271,2.492-0.694,3.508    c0.332-0.973,0.404-2.014,0.718-2.998c0.328-1.023,0.552-2.068,0.774-3.123c0.467-2.209,0.935-4.395,1.512-6.576    c0.495-1.877,0.932-3.811,1.614-5.637c0.477-1.273,0.665-2.67,1.23-3.91c0.622-1.359,1.315-2.705,1.886-4.102    c0.611-1.49,1.037-3.037,1.681-4.516c0.408-0.936,0.796-3.197,2.047-3.34c0.566,1.342-0.656,3.416-0.871,4.762    c-0.116,0.727-0.261,1.42-0.446,2.123c-0.205,0.785-0.185,1.332-0.258,2.115c-0.149,1.553-0.89,3.1-1.251,4.629    c-0.414,1.75-0.71,3.521-0.971,5.301c-0.448,3.059-0.783,6.131-1.388,9.158c-0.727,3.637-2.031,7.146-2.822,10.785    c-0.232,1.07-0.632,2.096-0.876,3.162c-0.235,1.031-0.506,2.139-0.604,3.174c0.489-1.223,0.822-2.646,1.213-3.918    c1.376-4.471,2.988-8.869,4.009-13.441c0.971-4.344,1.833-8.68,2.483-13.086c0.462-3.139,1.117-6.156,1.885-9.203    c0.322-1.279,0.455-3.619,1.375-4.613c0.538,1.023,2.034,1.885,3.043,2.365c0.768,0.365,1.637,0.893,2.472,1.016    c-0.405,1.115-0.652,2.426-0.987,3.619c-1.179,4.205-2.875,8.285-4.391,12.354c-1.043,2.801-1.652,5.73-2.485,8.598    c-0.945,3.248-1.729,6.545-2.835,9.746c-0.552,1.598-1.181,3.174-1.953,4.68c-0.326,0.635-0.49,1.268-0.77,1.898    c-0.332,0.748-1.013,1.348-1.47,2.018c0.9-0.625,1.44-2.063,2.012-2.986c0.497-0.803,0.963-1.549,1.373-2.42    c0.939-1.998,1.588-4.072,2.203-6.197c0.289-1.004,0.328-2.059,0.662-3.051c0.223-0.652,0.656-1.201,0.909-1.83    c0.354-0.879,0.527-1.836,0.821-2.736c0.35-1.072,0.792-2.129,1.18-3.186c0.256-0.701,0.477-1.441,0.687-2.15    c0.522-1.777,1.222-3.488,1.777-5.258c0.61-1.947,1.291-3.877,1.922-5.816c0.386-1.186,0.653-2.404,1.057-3.582    c0.367-1.07,0.926-2.025,1.293-3.08c0.367,0.061,0.833,0.219,1.208,0.359c0.601,0.223-1.846,8.178-2.071,8.98    c-1.199,4.27-1.939,8.619-3.483,12.77c-1.63,4.387-3.323,8.734-4.903,13.137c-0.52,1.449-1.034,2.971-1.227,4.506    c-0.078,0.615-0.304,1.633,0.003,2.215c0.672-0.713,0.846-2.449,1.116-3.395c0.713-2.496,1.632-4.928,2.501-7.361    c0.671-1.881,1.298-3.773,2.064-5.584c1.315-3.107,2.522-6.182,3.332-9.475c0.5-2.039,0.691-4.152,1.239-6.227    c0.471-1.779,0.899-3.563,1.514-5.305c0.483-1.367,0.966-2.607,1.095-4.072c0.832,0.607,2.354,0.24,3.293,0.223    c1.097-0.02,2.027-0.063,3.063,0.258c1.083,0.334,1.901-0.076,2.845-0.678c-0.009,0.482-0.338,1.105-0.488,1.59    c-0.249,0.809-0.511,1.592-0.811,2.375c-0.511,1.336-0.679,2.781-1.237,4.104c-1.115,2.639-3.014,4.867-4.191,7.514    c-1.048,2.355-2.287,4.598-3.194,7.021c-0.766,2.045-1.696,4.029-2.842,5.881c-0.983,1.59-1.957,3.18-2.929,4.771    c-0.711,1.16-1.616,2.16-2.385,3.27c0.652-0.455,1.155-1.299,1.682-1.9c0.648-0.746,1.368-1.473,1.967-2.236    c0.748-0.963,1.257-2.115,1.933-3.125c0.552-0.824,1.062-1.725,1.576-2.572c1.071-1.77,1.906-3.977,2.662-5.906    c0.729-1.861,1.632-3.676,2.488-5.459c1.419-2.957,3.453-5.482,4.727-8.518c0.562-1.34,0.861-2.52,1.138-3.912    c0.194-0.975,0.378-2.49,1.073-3.254c0.319-0.354,0.8-0.459,1.079-0.859c-0.464,0.67-0.155,1.449-0.186,2.186    c-0.062,1.52-0.255,3.123-0.677,4.576c-0.41,1.41-0.665,2.893-1.008,4.322c-0.185,0.771-0.374,1.535-0.624,2.287    c-0.592,1.773-1.144,3.418-2.158,4.969c-1.143,1.748-1.801,4.023-2.633,5.945c-1.804,4.17-3.666,8.324-5.851,12.311    c0.991-0.904,1.473-2.35,2.189-3.465c0.859-1.336,1.614-2.789,2.326-4.219c2.358-4.742,4.86-9.549,6.489-14.6    c1.122-3.479,2.078-7.15,2.659-10.76c0.203-1.266-0.071-2.629,0.282-3.854c0.119-0.416,0.143-0.432,0.596-0.707    c0.777-0.473,1.888-0.926,2.382-1.68c1.148,3.609,0.644,7.455-0.435,11.014c-1.042,3.439-2.245,6.791-3.981,9.945    c-0.938,1.701-1.949,3.361-2.907,5.055c-0.905,1.598-1.63,3.207-2.345,4.881c-0.535,1.258-1.09,2.691-1.927,3.771    c2.019-3.104,3.894-6.49,5.687-9.756c1.008-1.832,2.015-3.676,3.008-5.51c1.648-3.041,3.204-6.293,4.015-9.656    c0.292-1.213,0.689-2.547,0.816-3.777c0.137-1.311-0.256-2.813-0.406-4.115c-0.154-1.342-0.572-2.557-0.318-3.93    c0.216-1.164,0.795-2.27,1.096-3.422c0.673-2.584,0.347-5.152,0.527-7.785c0.23-3.398,1.137-6.703,1.737-10.045    c1.601-8.929,4.387-17.539,8.735-25.517c2.216-4.063,4.636-7.651,6.266-12.073c1.634-4.431,2.875-8.996,4.537-13.416    c2.067-5.495,4.231-10.953,6.354-16.426c1.52-3.919,3.303-7.737,4.688-11.709c1.044-2.993,1.324-6.161,1.743-9.283    c0.353-2.626,1.292-5.215,0.994-7.812c-0.696-6.045-1.526-11.863-3.335-17.701c-0.803-2.596-2.175-5.662-2.331-8.374    c-0.187-3.259,1.879-7.22,2.69-10.308c0.679-2.583,1.197-5.235,1.757-7.842c0.443-2.06,1.396-3.971,1.937-6.004    c0.202-0.761,0.297-4.746,1.198-5.016c0.739-0.221,2.136,1.858,2.553,2.314C222.815,277.855,223.931,279.344,225.042,280.882z     M212.536,317.179c0.501,1.833,0.804,3.729,1.007,5.584c0.696,6.376-0.067,12.832-1.493,19.057    c-0.651,2.844-1.561,5.61-1.921,8.457c-0.354,2.794-2.412,4.949-3.916,7.195c-2.784,4.157-6.772,7.28-10.44,10.614    c-3.069,2.79-6.133,6.084-8.109,9.752c-3.272,6.074-5.66,12.683-8.208,19.081c-1.58,3.962-3.147,7.929-4.621,11.932    c-0.744,2.021-1.463,4.049-2.149,6.09c-0.595,1.771-1.022,3.674-1.74,5.388c-0.427,1.021-1.153,1.888-1.784,2.785    c-0.646,0.918-1.256,1.842-1.998,2.688c-0.328,0.375-0.955,0.813-1.128,1.244c0.847-0.688,1.639-1.514,2.445-2.234    c0.746-0.668,1.291-1.609,1.997-2.336c0.115,1.199,0.147,2.451,0.147,3.656c0,1.447-0.361,2.861-0.337,4.309    c-0.008-0.494,0.288-1.229,0.375-1.74c0.098-0.576,0.249-1.156,0.504-1.674c0.716,0.426,0.727,1.697,1.041,2.4    c0.075-0.293-0.136-0.684-0.2-0.979c-0.159-0.727-0.286-1.479-0.466-2.197c-0.205-0.82-0.298-1.666-0.224-2.51    c0.067-0.748-0.028-1.703,0.24-2.412c0.469-1.231,0.94-2.465,1.411-3.697c-0.117,0.305,0.826,1.473,0.972,1.721    c0.156,0.264,0.963,1.244,0.946,1.496c0.06-0.894-0.926-1.841-1.201-2.688c-0.147-0.452-0.374-1.155-0.338-1.624    c0.057-0.754,0.448-1.579,0.688-2.294c0.521-1.552,1.129-3.045,1.712-4.57c3.037-7.935,6.512-15.704,9.204-23.769    c2.415-7.237,7.141-13.387,12.924-18.35c3.229-2.771,6.165-5.877,9.287-8.643c-1.423,4.813-3.315,9.386-4.876,14.132    c-1.108,3.366-2.308,6.702-3.572,10.012c-2.925,7.667-7.165,14.424-10.591,21.833c-2.661,5.755-4.731,11.782-6.163,17.958    c-1.176,5.08-3.431,9.514-8.162,12.162c-4.209,2.357-10.499,0.795-14.103-2.031c-5.37-4.211-1.755-7.447,2.019-10.521    c2.807-2.289,4.649-5.178,6.387-8.18c3.61-6.24,3.58-12.532,4.882-19.43c2.008-10.639,4.326-21.665,5.759-32.401    c1.665-12.469,4.51-25.576,10.62-36.664c3.583-6.499,9.439-11.292,14.943-16.097c2.12-1.851,3.446-1.211,5.108,0.932    C210.918,312.553,211.89,314.814,212.536,317.179z M329.596,128.031c-0.061,2.235-0.129,4.469-0.09,6.736    c0.085,4.995,0.234,9.99,0.294,14.985c0.054,4.589-0.406,9.159-0.609,13.74c-0.176,3.926-0.859,7.661-0.622,11.64    c0.146,2.467,0.012,4.969-0.323,7.416c-0.179,1.293-0.325,4.084-1.494,4.957c-1.97,1.468-7.185-7.475-8.486-9.04    c-1.838-2.206-4.219-4.276-5.725-6.696c-1.418-2.281-1.217-5.724-1.641-8.308c-0.487-2.983-0.935-5.975-1.409-8.971    c-1.044-6.583-1.997-13.18-3.165-19.744c-0.783-4.385-1.375-8.801-1.91-13.222c-0.747-6.149-0.266-12.63-0.111-18.813    c0.232-9.328-0.779-18.699-1.344-28.009c-0.186-3.085-0.816-6.272-0.671-9.347c0.04-0.886,0.295-1.913,0.831-2.639    c0.621-0.84,1.462-0.873,2.324-1.369c-0.463,0.197-0.912,0.424-1.248,0.784c0.254-0.273,2.544,0.356,3.055,0.253    c0.646-0.13,1.569-0.571,2.062-1.005c1.743,1.843,4.834,1.294,7.095,1.707c1.597,0.291,3.104,0.813,4.71,0.533    c1.287-0.226,2.511-0.978,3.781-1.174c1.083-0.166,2.173,0.624,3.22,0.213c1.063-0.418,2.795-1.979,4.006-0.952    c-0.321-0.446-0.753-0.92-1.173-1.294c3.825,2.409,3.537,5.449,2.48,9.464c-0.667,2.542-1.537,5.206-1.69,7.858    c-0.172,2.926-0.179,5.826-0.32,8.75c-0.366,7.618-1.039,15.144-1.439,22.761c-0.002,0.059-0.007,0.118-0.01,0.178    c-0.209,3.781-0.498,7.653-0.353,11.449C329.711,123.288,329.656,125.661,329.596,128.031z M179.538,444.593    c-0.398,1.477-1.063,2.832-2.472,3.984c-0.749,0.615-1.634,1.178-2.502,1.607c-3.585,1.783-7.581,2.182-11.522,1.418    c-1.591-0.309-2.688-1.139-4.061-1.848c-1.409-0.729-2.834-1.424-4.042-2.473c-2.001-1.734-3.116-4.104-3.863-6.6    c-0.29-0.965-0.56-1.939-0.64-2.947c-0.082-1.016,0.178-1.658,0.286-2.643c0.543,0.57,0.802,1.543,1.312,2.199    c0.729,0.939,1.59,1.766,2.394,2.631c1.739,1.873,3.667,3.49,6.139,4.24c2.958,0.898,6.226,1.65,9.323,1.207    c0.885-0.129,1.739-0.311,2.626-0.447c0.574-0.09,2.126-0.99,0.886-1.119c-0.451-0.047-1.338,0.436-1.792,0.541    c-0.798,0.189-1.604,0.344-2.423,0.402c-1.471,0.105-2.99-0.035-4.445-0.27c-2.355-0.379-4.702-1.008-6.589-2.477    c-1.806-1.406-3.578-2.869-4.966-4.707c-0.787-1.041-1.731-2.26-1.901-3.596c-0.186-1.48,1.123-2.566,1.833-3.729    c0.365-0.6,0.844-1.064,1.236-1.633c0.33-0.475,1.117-1.365,1.235-1.918c-0.357,1.691,0.297,3.352,1.058,4.834    c0.445,0.865,0.973,1.836,1.686,2.506c1.72,1.617,3.344,2.93,5.669,3.619c1.455,0.434,2.98,0.633,4.498,0.584    c2.639-0.084,5.266-0.811,7.504-2.227c2.33-1.477,3.647-3.563,5.387-5.609c0.15,0.791-0.279,1.867-0.425,2.656    c-0.197,1.057-0.292,2.053-0.289,3.127c0.004,1.285,0.003,2.689-0.264,3.967C180.069,441.519,179.937,443.117,179.538,444.593z     M447.202,371.869c0.011,0.163,0.021,0.325,0.032,0.486c0.133,2.064,0.249,4.059,0.526,6.115    c0.591,4.384,0.997,8.805,1.331,13.207c0.659,8.611,1.502,17.218,2.331,25.797c0.298,3.095,1.721,6.422,1.067,9.471    c-0.625,2.93-1.925,5.619-3.336,8.244c-0.449,0.836-0.99,1.59-1.196,2.52c-0.159,0.713-0.075,1.473-0.295,2.16    c-1.066,3.344-5.133,5.506-8.403,3.945c-4.102-1.951-0.917-8.395-2.081-11.818c-0.634-1.867-1.584-3.529-2.269-5.365    c-0.963-2.592-2.111-4.557-1.454-7.343c0.594-2.507,1.144-5.365,0.786-7.94c-0.327-2.342-0.549-4.733-0.891-7.096    c-0.761-5.265-2.094-10.422-3.135-15.633c-0.638-3.199-1.117-6.444-1.688-9.645c-0.407-2.271-0.698-4.563-1.198-6.816    c-0.385-1.738-0.322-3.435-0.682-5.172c-0.946-4.593-1.767-9.204-2.394-13.852c-0.171-1.255-2.769-17.072-0.732-17.059    c0.537,0.003,0.78,0.787,0.992,1.168c0.789,1.412,1.423,2.978,2.082,4.431c0.825,1.814,1.805,3.548,2.488,5.441    c1.107,3.056,2.099,6.354,2.731,9.536c0.444,2.238,1.519,4.422,1.646,6.706c0.1,1.761,0.679,3.288,1.022,5.009    c0.379,1.909,0.556,3.85,0.785,5.78c0.387,3.22,0.485,6.494-0.26,9.674c-0.207,0.88-0.806,2.242-0.359,3.011    c0.554-1.147,0.741-2.543,1.188-3.731c0.117-0.007,0.226-0.004,0.345-0.002c1.088,3.927,1.432,7.843,1.698,11.87    c0.128,1.944,0.267,3.918,0.389,5.881c0.104,1.685,0.607,3.48,0.554,5.14c0.621-1.348-0.102-4.158-0.156-5.725    c-0.064-1.679-0.02-3.351-0.134-5.012c-0.194-2.795-0.266-5.759-0.799-8.515c-0.654-3.367-1.131-6.763-1.564-10.163    c-0.352-2.753-0.198-5.33-0.698-8.075c-1.237-6.789-2.154-13.684-4.588-20.181c-1.123-3.001-2.298-5.904-3.669-8.78    c-2.333-4.9-4.923-10.387-4.276-15.858c0.81-6.854,1.105-13.467,2.681-20.252c0.208-0.895,0.733-4.314,1.466-4.851    c4.69-3.434,14.815,14.694,15.577,18.016c1.396,6.08,3.309,11.661,3.703,17.971c0.629,10.021,0.615,19.184-3.292,28.472    c-1.432,3.402-2.641,6.766-3.47,10.378c-1.262,5.505-0.255,10.896-0.198,16.443c0.023,2.405,0.076,4.813,0.188,7.217    c0.105,2.272,0.521,4.249,0.892,6.453c1.057,6.309,0.963,12.724,1.053,19.084c0.042,3.121-0.279,7.529,1.011,10.154    c-0.313-2.9-0.204-5.818-0.169-8.729c0.018-1.576-0.9-5.697,0.221-6.895c1.953,2.353,2.143,7.598,2.665,10.526    c0.486,2.734,0.312,5.693,0.252,8.498c0.764-1.828,0.168-4.322,0.326-6.287c0.561,0.494,1.063,1.43,1.778,1.822    c-0.021-1.285-1.294-2.609-1.572-3.975c-0.358-1.762-0.423-3.568-0.851-5.324c-0.367-1.505-0.626-2.925-1.383-4.262    c-0.776-1.377-1.362-2.938-1.659-4.5c-0.332-1.743-0.159-3.646-0.221-5.411c-0.059-1.737-0.403-3.469-0.598-5.207    c-0.422-3.82-0.552-7.673-0.321-11.513c0.228-3.78-0.573-7.342-0.931-11.014c-0.36-3.666,0.666-7.725,1.916-11.139    c1.609-4.403,2.944-8.904,5.131-13.075C447.043,361.432,446.9,366.73,447.202,371.869z M457.845,446.414    c0.538,1.311,1.132,2.695,1.27,4.082c0.246,2.463-1.562,4.734-3.186,6.381c-4.137,4.188-11.606,6.857-17.426,5.365    c-2.867-0.732-6.18-1.684-8.407-3.713c-2.394-2.176-4.974-4.182-6.469-7.145c-2.041-4.049,1.097-8.176,3.024-11.52    c0.173-0.039,0.313-0.023,0.485-0.002c0.211,0.021,2.025,3.869,2.345,4.309c2.311,3.209,5.156,6.207,8.861,7.775    c2.571,1.09,5.807,2.498,8.588,1.664c2.151-0.645,4.987-2.104,5.879-4.316c-1.662,0.875-2.844,2.193-4.752,2.801    c-3.021,0.959-7.968,0.262-10.543-1.688c-1.364-1.031-2.995-1.781-4.26-2.969c-2.254-2.117-3.346-4.885-4.332-7.766    c-0.746-2.182,1.271-4.969,2.01-6.988c0.214-0.58,1.966-6.779,1.99-6.779c0.613-0.012,0.787,0.984,1.053,1.496    c0.522,1.01,1.414,1.881,1.306,3.115c-0.086,0.98-0.993,1.928-0.779,2.914c0.001,0.004,1.1-1.873,1.323-1.951    c1.062,2.502,0.325,4.357,0.204,6.971c-0.097,2.068,0.502,4.656,2.312,5.912c1.49,1.035,3.411,0.578,5.178,0.688    c-0.13,0.523-0.03,1.189-0.229,1.682c0.04,0.055,0.088,0.094,0.148,0.115c0.616-0.744,0.62-1.563,1.297-2.318    c0.601-0.668,1.414-1.248,2.021-1.896c0.751-0.801,1.339-1.439,1.572-2.523c0.248-1.156,0.275-2.422,1.44-3.059    c0.338,1.145,0.103,2.92,0.658,3.844c0.227-2.258-0.584-4.455,0.196-6.545c0.534-1.428,1.298-2.652,1.802-4.1    c0.341-0.979,0.688-2.115,1.229-2.947c0.57,1.01,0.508,3.152,0.66,4.416c0.2,1.666,0.021,3.463,0.284,5.088    c0.511,3.148,1.861,6.18,3.048,9.123C457.712,446.093,457.776,446.253,457.845,446.414z"/>
```

Comment: That's possible for the heart but a lot of the arteries aren't individual objects.